# Ĉu la verbo "egali" bezonas akuzativon?

Tags: accusative

Duolingo diras: *"Uno minus unu egalas nuloN."* Sed diras: *"Ĉu naŭdek minus okdek egalas dek?"*

**Kial en la unua frazo, oni aldonas l'akuzativon al la nulo, sed en la dua frazo ne aldonas tion al dek (dek+o+n=dekon)?**

Answer (score 3):

Jes, *egali* (kiam ĝi signifas *esti egala al*) postulas akuzativon.

Sed tiu frazo estas malĝusta, ĝi devus esti:

```
Unu minus unu egalas nul.
```

Kial? Ĉar tiuokaze *nul* estas [rekta nombra priskribo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/uzado.html#j-j14).

El [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html):

```
Divido per nul ne estas permesita.
```

Do, kiam oni uzas la vorton *nulo*? Vidu ekzemplon el la proverbaro Zamenhofa (mi pensas ke estas pli facile tion kompreni per ekzemplo):

```
Sen mono oni estas nulo, kun mono – saĝulo.
```

Comment: Sinjoro Trápani, dankegon pro via utila respondo. Do, ĉu oni devas aldoni -n finaĵon al nombroj, ĉiam uzante la verbon "egali"?

Comment: [Nombraj vortetoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/vortetoj/uzado.html) (_nul, unu, du, tri, kvar, kvin, ses, sep, ok, naŭ, dek, cent, mil_) neniam ricevas finaĵojn. Ekzistas ankaŭ **substantivoj** _nulo, unuo, duo…, miliono, miliardo…_, kiuj ricevas finaĵojn normale. Notu, ke signifoj de nombraj vortetoj kaj substanstivoj ne estas samaj.

Answer (score 3):

Historie unue nur ekzistis la substantivo ***nulo***; pro tio *egalas nulon*. Post tempo la Akademio de Esperanto oficialigis la numeralon ***nul***. Do pli aktuala lingvouzo estus ***egalas nul***.

*Egali* estas uzeble kun *al*, sene kun akuzativo. Proksima verbo estas *simili*.

Krome estas la refleksiva uzo.

> Ili egalas (unu al la alia / unu la alian).

Comment: Dankon Sinjor' Eggen, pro via utila respondo. Do, ĉu "egali" bezonas akuzativon, sed "egali al" ne bezonas akuzativon?

Comment: @Qàtrè la ekzemploj montras ke la ellaso de `al` necesigas akuzativon. Miaopinie nominativo same validus teorie - kompareble al _esti_. Krome: _nulo egalas tri minus tri_.

Comment: Dankegon denove, Sinjor' Eggen!

Comment: @JoopEggen _nul egalas tri minus tri_.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: _unu la alian_ aŭ _unu al la alia_, ĉu ne?

Comment: @Vidamuzo jes, mi ekkomprenas la idistojn. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ĝi ja bezonas akuzativon. [Vortaro montras tion](http://vortaro.net/#egali), kaj inkluzivas eĉ ekzemplon de Zamenhof kun akuzativo.

Sed Duolingo ne faras eraron (redakto: pri la dua frazo. En la unua frazo eble ja estas eraro, kiel rimarkis Eduardo); ĝi uzas la numeralon *dek* en la dua ekzemplo, kiun vi donas, ne la o-vorton *deko*. *Dek* estas la nombro/numero mem; *deko* estas substantivo. Tial oni vidas la diferencon inter "dek katoj" kaj "deko *da* katoj", ekzemple. La numeralo ne bezonas—eĉ ne povas havi—akuzativon.

Comment: Ne bezoni akuzativon via lgilo ne montras, nur ellasas "unu al la alia". Cetere valora komento.

Comment: Sinjoro @Oostelbos, dankon pro via provo de helpi min.

Comment: @JoopEggen, vi pravas. Mi misskribis, mi volis fakte skribi, ke ĝi ja postulas akuzativon. Kaj estas tio, kion la ekzemploj sur tiu retpaĝo montras. Ups!